# QML Gauge. Как сделать индикатор от нуля?

Tags: qt, qml

Всем привет! Вопрос следующий. Как мне можно сделать индикатор Gauge, от -5000 до 5000, чтобы полоса начинала всегда заполняться с нуля? На данный момент у меня получилось написать следующий код:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras.Private 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtCharts 2.3

Window {
    id: winapp
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 630
    color: "#1b2153"
    title: qsTr("FirstProject")

    Gauge {
        id: gauge1
        x: 20
        y: 53
        width: 44
        height: 547
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 30
        value: 1246
        minimumValue: -5000
        maximumValue: 5000
        tickmarkStepSize: 500
        formatValue: function(value) {
            return value.toFixed(0);
        }
        property double minBarValue: 0
        style: GaugeStyle{
            valueBar: Item {
                 implicitWidth: 16
                 Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: (gauge1.value === gauge1.minimumValue) ? 0 : parent.height /     (gauge1.value - gauge1.minimumValue) * (gauge1.value - gauge1.minBarValue)
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно картинка следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я хочу поставить текущее значение value например -1000 индикатор перестает работать. Я не могу понять где ошибка. Пожалуйста подскажите

Comment: Задать `value: 0` не пробовали?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin `value: 0` - отвечает за текущее значение на индикаторе. В Данном случае value: 1000 то есть от 0 до 1000 индикатор показывает

Comment: Покрутил я вашу проблему и похоже никак. Пробовал и на чистом qml и при помощи C++ (наследника `QQuickPaintedItem`) и ничего не получилось и такое чувство, что я что-то упускаю. Надо задать этот вопрос разработчикам

Comment: у меня тоже такое чувство. Мне кажется, что все дело в функции `valuePosition`

Comment: valuePosition - это текущее значение в пикселях высоты виджета. Он не установит начало в 0, и вряд ли будет отрицательным. Будет время, покручу еще

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже этим займусь. Но идеи к сожалению уже давно закончились как это реализовать

Comment: У вас при отрицательном значении value - высота получается отрицательной. Надо брать модуль и координату по y вашего прямоугольника менять в зависимости от знака либо 0 либо -height